# Adding a method to all HTML elements and document object in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-9

I want to add a method to all HTML elements and the document object in JavaScript.
After some googling I found http://krook.org/jsdom/.
I concluded that adding a method to the `Node` class would do the job, 
and indeed in Firefox and Chrome this worked.

Below is pretty much what I did.

```
<script>
Node.prototype.foo=function(selector){
    alert('succes');
}
document.foo();
document.getElementById("foo").foo();
</script>
```

In Internet Explorer it causes an error because `Node` is not defined.
Does anyone know how to do this in Internet Explorer?

Oh also, I'm using Internet Explorer 9.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IE DOM won't allow JavaScript to access the constructors for prototyping, so element/Node prototyping is not supported by the IE DOM natively (IE 10 runs your code fine, as I suspect does IE 0).

What are you trying to achieve? There are [arguments against doing DOM extensions](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) - there is probably another way to do it.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. Since IE8, you can use `Element.prototype.foo = ...` to add a custom method to all DOM elements in the current document. Not saying that it's a good idea though...